# Eclipselink Maven No Persistence provider for EntityManager named

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I try to create a JPA Project with Maven in Intellij. 
I use Eclipse Link and the Database is SQlite.

This is my current `pom.xml` File (only the Dependencies):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
  <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.11.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

My `persistence.xml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">
<persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.raeste.db.BuchungEntity</class>
    <class>com.raeste.db.KategorieEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:/home/raeste/programmierung/haushaltsbuch.db"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

If i now try to create an `EntityMangerFactory` I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named NewPersistenceUnit
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
```

The Code to create the `EntityManagerFactory` is:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit");
```

I know there are several questions with that problem but non of them helped.
The `persistence.xml` file is under the following path:

```
src/main/java/META-INF/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `persistence.xml` file should be at `src/main/resources/META-INF`. 
`src/main/java` is for Java source code.
`src/main/resources` is for resource files.

Try it.